# Facing NoSuchMethodError for io.netty.util.AttributeKey.valueOf() method with grpc and protobuf Hello world example

Tags: java, maven-2, netty, protocol-buffers, grpc-java

After running GreetingServerTest.java tests I am getting below given errors. I am using grpc 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT libraries and trying to implement basic Helloword example of grpc given in there git repo. Can anybody please suggest which libraries I am missing or there's anything else I need to do.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.util.AttributeKey.valueOf(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Lio/netty/util/AttributeKey;
at io.grpc.netty.Utils.<clinit>(Utils.java:87)
at io.grpc.netty.NettyServer.allocateSharedGroups(NettyServer.java:187)
at io.grpc.netty.NettyServer.start(NettyServer.java:116)
at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:156)
at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:83)
at com.xyz.communication.datacollection.GrpcServerTest.test(GrpcServerTest.java:23)
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.springframework.samples</groupId>
<artifactId>InternodeCommunication</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <spring-framework.version>4.3.1.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

    <!-- Kundera JPA -->
    <kundera-version>3.4</kundera-version>

    <!-- Hibernate jpa -->
    <hibernate.version>4.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>


    <!-- Test -->
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <grpc.version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</grpc.version>
    <!-- Generic properties -->
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- kafka -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka_2.10 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.0.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
        <artifactId>Common</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>18.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-netty</artifactId>
        <version>${grpc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
        <version>${grpc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
        <version>${grpc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.grpc/grpc-all -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-codec -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-all -->




    <!-- Test Artifacts -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
        <artifactId>Common</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.Final</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- The version of protoc must match protobuf-java. If you don't depend 
                    on protobuf-java directly, you will be transitively depending on the protobuf-java 
                    version that grpc depends on. -->
                <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
                <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

hello_world.proto file

```
syntax = "proto3";
option java_multiple_files = true;
package com.xyz.communication.example;
message HelloRequest {
 string name = 1;
}
message HelloResponse {
  string greeting = 1;
}
service GreetingService {
   rpc greeting(HelloRequest) returns (HelloResponse);
}
```

GreetingServerTest.java

```
@ContextConfiguration("/communication-test-beans.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class GrpcServerTest {
    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        io.grpc.Server server = ServerBuilder.forPort(8080).addService(new GrpcServerImpl().bindService()).build();
        server.start();
        server.awaitTermination();
    }
}

class GrpcServerImpl extends GreetingServiceGrpc.GreetingServiceImplBase {
    @Override
    public void greeting(HelloRequest request, StreamObserver<HelloResponse> responseObserver) {
        HelloResponse response = HelloResponse.newBuilder().setGreeting("Hello " + request.getName()).build();
        responseObserver.onNext(response);
        responseObserver.onCompleted();
    }

    @Override
    public ServerServiceDefinition bindService() {
        return super.bindService();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There could be multiple versions of netty jar in you class path during runtime. Use following command to check  dependency tree.

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

Or your container provides the netty jar might be clashing with the version of jar you packaging with your application.

Comment: What exactly was the problem? How did you fix it?

Comment: There were different libraries and some of them using netty with different versions. Using mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose you will know which netty version is used by which component. Based on this information find out in which component you need to tell them to not to download the netty jar @navige

Comment: @nikhilbhr Can you share what your pom file looked like?  The specific excludes you may have added would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me.  I needed to shade io.netty and com.google.

```html
   <relocation>
      <pattern>io.netty</pattern>
      <shadedPattern>myshade.io.netty</shadedPattern>
    </relocation>
    <relocation>
       <pattern>com.google</pattern>
       <shadedPattern>myshade.com.google</shadedPattern>
   </relocation>
```