# NoSuchMethodError for io.netty.util.AttributeKey.valueOf()

Tags: scala, apache-spark, netty, grpc

I am having troubles with a NoSuchMethodError ([similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39450150/facing-nosuchmethoderror-for-io-netty-util-attributekey-valueof-method-with-gr)) in a Spark 2.1/grpc 1.0.1 application that I packed using sbt-assembly. When starting the gRPC server using

```
NettyServerBuilder.forPort(port)
  .addService(...)
  .build.start
```

I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-21" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.util.AttributeKey.valueOf(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Lio/netty/util/AttributeKey;
at io.grpc.netty.Utils.<clinit>(Utils.java:85)
at io.grpc.netty.NettyServer.allocateSharedGroups(NettyServer.java:187)
at io.grpc.netty.NettyServer.start(NettyServer.java:116)
at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:147)
...
```

I have used `sbt show update`, `sbt evicted` to try to find where the error comes from. As a consequence I now exclude `io.netty` using

```
.map(_.excludeAll(ExclusionRule("io.netty")))
```

and then include

```
Seq(
  "io.netty" % "netty-buffer" % "4.1.6.Final",
  "io.netty" % "netty-codec" % "4.1.6.Final",
  "io.netty" % "netty-codec-http" % "4.1.6.Final",
  "io.netty" % "netty-codec-http2" % "4.1.6.Final",
  "io.netty" % "netty-codec-socks" % "4.1.6.Final",
  "io.netty" % "netty-common" % "4.1.6.Final",
  "io.netty" % "netty-handler" % "4.1.6.Final",
  "io.netty" % "netty-handler-proxy" % "4.1.6.Final",
  "io.netty" % "netty-resolver" % "4.1.6.Final",
  "io.netty" % "netty-transport" % "4.1.6.Final"
)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't help. I also unzipped the jar I submit to spark and looked at the classes included there and using `java -p AttributeKey` I get (in the folder ./io/netty/util there are two files  AttributeKey.class and  AttributeKey$1.class, but that doesn't cause the problem, right?)

```
Warning: Binary file AttributeKey contains io.netty.util.AttributeKey
Compiled from "AttributeKey.java"
...
  public static <T> io.netty.util.AttributeKey<T> valueOf(java.lang.String);
...
```

So the method is there, but I honestly do not understand what raises this error. Do you have any suggestions how to further proceed here?

**Update**: I guess the problem is that submitting the Spark application will make use of the libraries that come with Spark. Therefore, my attempt with including netty 4.1.6 will not change anything, as it will be overwritten by the Spark default netty. You may use `spark.driver.userClassPathFirst`, but it is considered experimental.

**Update 2**: I have used shading (using sbt-assembly) on both `io.netty.**` and `com.google.**` (apparently some guava version is also in conflict...) and now it works.

Comment: Did you solve it or is there still a question?  It isn't clear after your second update what you are asking.